AWS Opensearch request signature matching issue
Cretaed an AWS Opensearch and lambda in a single VPC. And inside the lambda I have the given code. When I try to invoke the lambda it shows the given error.
I don't know how the signature works.
Error Message
Lambda code for accessing AWS Opensearch 
Could you please help me to solve this.
I trigger this lambda through ApiGatway.
Lambda is in public subnet, AWS Opensearch in Private Subnet

Please edit the question and paste the error output and code as text in blocks delimited by triple-back-ticks. You might need to pare your code to make a minimal reproducible example.

Does this answer your question? Amazon S3 - How to fix 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature' error?
